# Drupal 9 webforms, twig email doesn't contain complete path to files

Tags: webforms, upload, twig, drupal-8

I have a webform that allows image uploads and, upon submission, emails information in HTML via a TWIG template. I am using the following TWIG to output the image upload field:

```
{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:photos_upload_new]', webform_submission, [], options) }}
```

That’s printing a CVS list of links to the files on the server (GREAT!) but the hrefs do not contain the domain name (bad) so the link to the images is “broken” in the email.

Sample:

```
<span>
  <a href="/system/files/webform/webform_26816/478711/rc_banner.jpg">rc_banner.jpg</a>
</span> , 
<span> 
  <a href="/system/files/webform/webform_26816/478711/img_6842.jpg">img_6842.jpg</a> 
</span>
```

I tried a custom file-link.html.twig template, but that doesn’t have the granularity I need to add the domain to the link. Then I thought I could use hook_preprocess_file_link, but that appears to use a URL object that I can’t modify appropriately.  I thought maybe we could add a “base href” definition to the email, but it doesn’t look like that’s a best practice.

Am I missing something simple? Any ideas for how to fix this?